# How to have a button that sorts and another button that reverses the word density of my text?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want to have something like this because it's ugly to see:
[image]

But instead, I want my word density to get more organized and sorted out. How do I accomplish all this?

1. *Sort* from the **highest word density first** as a *default*.
2. Have a button to *reverse* (or have the **lowest word density first**).
3. And then another button that sorts the highest word density first (like the default).

Here's my HTML:

```js
const displayText = () => {
  const inputPage = document.getElementById("input-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");
  const text = document.getElementById("text");
  const textValue = text.value;

  if (text.value !== "") {
    // normal flow will continue if the text-area is not empty
    inputPage.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("display-text").innerText = textValue;
    countPage.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // if the text-area is empty, it will issue a warning.
    alert("Please enter some text first.");
  }

  const countWords = (str) => {
    return str.split(" ").length;
  };
  const wordCount = countWords(textValue);

  const renderWordCount = () => {
    const wordCountDiv = document.getElementById("word-count");
    wordCountDiv.innerHTML = "<h1> Words Counted: " + wordCount + "</h1>";
  };

  const getWordDensity = (str) => {
    let wordList = {};
    str.split(/[\s.,—–]+/).forEach((word) => { // '\s.,—–' removes space or tab, periods, commas, em and en dashes from the text.
      if (typeof wordList[word] == "undefined") {
        wordList[word] = 1;
      } else {
        wordList[word]++;
      }
    });
    return wordList;
  };
  const wordDensity = getWordDensity(textValue);

  const renderWordDensity = () => {
    const wordDensityDiv = document.getElementById("word-density");

    let table = "<table>";
    for (let word in wordDensity) {
      table +=
        "<tr><td>" + word + "</td><td>" + wordDensity[word] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";

    wordDensityDiv.innerHTML = "<h1> Word Density: </h1>" + table;
  };

  renderWordCount();
  renderWordDensity();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Word Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="input-page">
    <h1>Word Counter</h1>
    <form action="">
      <textarea id="text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
      <br />
    </form>
    <button onclick="displayText()">COUNT</button>
  </div>

  <div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Your Text:</h1>
    <p id="display-text"></p>
    <div id="word-count"></div>
    <div id="word-density"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What did you try to achieve that?

Comment: I recommend you to have the words in an array instead of rendering it right from the analyzing. Then, render the array as you like. This way it will much easier for you to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going to be able to sort your words correctly, because you are are storing them in an object. Instead store them in an array like this:

```
wordList = [
  {
    word: "the",
    count: 5,
  },{
    word: "pizza",
    count: 2,
  },
]
```

When you store the data like that, you can sort the array using a custom sort function:

```
const highestFirst = true;
wordList.sort( (a,b) => {
  if( a.count == b.count ) return 0;
  if( highestFirst )
    return (a.count < b.count) ? -1 : 1;
  else
    return (a.count > b.count) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

So have your button run the above function to sort the array, then loop through the array, and for each print out the row. Something like:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
wordList.forEach( w => {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let td1 = document.createElement('td');
  let td2 = document.createElement('td');
  td1.innerText = w.word;
  td2.innerText = w.count;
  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```